# can i publish my chatbot on twitter without azure ?(MS Bot Framework)

Tags: twitter, botframework, azure-bot-service

i made a simple bot with Microsoft Bot Framework and i want to use my bot on unsopported channels(direct line channel) like twitter, instagram. So please help me to connect the bot to channels without Azure.

Comment: Why would it be "without Azure"? If your need is to connect to unsupported channel like Twitter, just ask for it and show what you tried / think about it, but it's not necessary to point to a "way" which may be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unsupported channels you don't need to connect your bot through Direct Line. Twitter has a [public API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs.html), so you can just create a custom Connector and then still use the BotBuilder SDK to develop bots. This way you wouldn't be going through Azure.

> Note: Read [Instagram's docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) on their [API deprecation](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/) and see if it's applicable to you.

An example of a custom connector for supporting [LINE](https://line.me/en/?) can be found under the [`botbuilder-linebot-connector`](https://github.com/Wolke/botbuilder-linebot-connector).

Comment: @reardeltoit were you able to connect twitter and bot framework?